# Lightbox2 - display div's content instead of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to know how to use Lightbox2 to display the contents of a div.

Currently I am using the following line of code to display an image.

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">image #1</a>
```

Is it possible to display a div's content instead of the image?

Thanks for any hints provided :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightbox is for images.
If you're looking to display content, create a new page and embed an iframe with Fancybox: http://fancybox.net/

To do iframe, include jquery, then the necissary fancybox javascript & css files you can download, then call it with this code:

```
<script>
$("a.fancyiframe").fancybox({
    'type':'iframe',
});
</script>
```

then setup your link element:

```
<a class="fancyiframe" href="http://www.yoursite.com/place.html">This goes to iframe</a>
```